# Understanding LumenSyntax: router->get()

Tags: php, lumen

I'm new to Lumen and even using the official Doc: https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing
I find it pretty hard to deduct what's happening behind the curtains/syntax.
I'm currently using the following video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Oxfb_HNY0U 
na fresh lumen project for testing purposes:

In this question, I want to specifically understand what this syntax does:

```
File: web.php (located inside /routes)
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It is a breeze. Simply tell Lumen the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the Closure to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

$router->group(['prefix' => 'api'], function($router){
  $router->get('articles', 'ArticleController@showAllArticles');
});
```

It's the parameters of "router->get()" that bother me. 
I do understand the second parameter. 
ArticleController@showAllArticles points to the file: ArticleController.php inside /app/http/controllers and then its function showAllArticles, as seen here in the code of ArticleController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Article;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    //

    public function showAllArticles(){
      return response()->json(Article::all());
    }
}
```

But I don't really understand the first parameter. "articles" is indeed the name of the referenced table on the DB Im using. 
The "Article" model used in the above code is defined inside

/app/article.php :

```
<?php

namespace App;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'description', 'status'
    ];

}
```

According to the official doc, the first param is the URI. 
Well that's all nice and fine, but the doc doesn't really specify the scope of this URI.
Obviously its not being inserted into the callback code of showAllArticles inside ArticleController.php.

But I want to track down where exactly this parameter gets inserted and what the functionality looks like, but I got lost in the depths of the framework code.

I need to know where this URI is actually used because my code isn't working as expected. 
I can indeed fetch data from my DB, but its not the data I specified. 
The Article model is designed to reference three attributes from the articles table, but I get all of the six attributes of the table, see screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/skzcQ.jpg

Comment: as a get, you need to fetch only 3 attributes that you can do with 
public function showAllArticles(){
      return response()->json(Article::get(['title', 'description', 'status']));
    }

Comment: Man you really need to learn about laravel first.
I can give you some short description here is that, url in the `$router->get('articles',...)` is not depend on any tables.

Comment: also getting an attribute from model or table ist not have any relation with your route param in your case

Comment: it only indicated on which url what controller method should call. Plus you have given eloquent all method which simply like 'select * from`

Comment: `$fillable` is used when you want to create and save object using model like this `$artical = new Artical(["title"=>"asd","description"=>"desc","status"=>1])

Comment: This will only allow these three columns to create a new object like this. If you add any other column in this array you will get an exception.

Comment: @Dhaval Purohit
Yeah the problem is that it was decided we work with lumen and not laravel, and I'm expected to get a grip of it quickly. Dunno either if this will work out in the end, lumen was chosen because it is supposed to be easier to learn since its a small framework than full blown laravel.

Anyway, your comments already helped me a lot in deciphering the syntax! :=)

Comment: Yeah it's true lumen is lightweight but all the flaw and everything is same as laravel. In short you can convert all the lumen code into laravel in no time just by copy pasting into the laravel build.

Comment: As mentioned earlier in the comments, it would be beneficial for you to understand the basics with Laravel before diving in to Lumen. Here is a very good course to help you get started: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-6-from-scratch/episodes/5